# PCI DSS 1.2.1 Restrict inbound and outbound traffic to that which is necessary for the cardholder data environment

Tags: pci-dss

A strict interpretation of that rule would seem to prohibit any non-payment related web browsing by PCs that are used to transmit card details to a payment processor, and perhaps also prohibit web browsing by any PCs on the same LAN as a card processing PC.

However, it appears that rule has been interpreted by others more broadly.

> In requirement 1.2, we are ensuring that the firewall configuration is
>   designed to be least allowed – allowing the least number of ports
>   necessary for business to occur. This does not require you to drop
>   everything, you must justify each port required and implement only
>   those required to do business. An untrusted network is one which your
>   firm does not control, such as the Internet or a partner network.

[source](http://learnthat.com/pci-security-standard-requirement-1/)

> Specific to PCI DSS 1.2.1, it says that your organization is only
>   allowed to use the protocols, ports, and services that are required
>   for the operation of your business.

[source](https://kirkpatrickprice.com/video/pci-dss-requirement-1-2-1-restrict-traffic-to-that-which-is-necessary/)

Can anyone provide confirmation or clarification?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Originally, PCI-DSS was meant to enforce a separation of cardholder data processing and the rest of the business. In that context, no, there should be no browsing in that environment.

Since the initial release, there has been a lot of abstraction of what a "cardholder data processing environment" actually is with a lot of hybrid environments. So now, the processing environment and the business environment are co-mingled. In this context, one would *need* to interpret the standard more broadly in the way that you described.

So, in the end, it depends on your environment, your scope, your boundaries, and your QSA's interpretation of all three.

Comment: I'm going to advise my client to use dedicated card payment terminals which WorldPay claim can be used in any Wifi environment https://www.worldpay.com/en-gb/products/portable-card-machines

Comment: That's generally the best way to go. Keep the scope in someone else's environment.